# Windows 7 Calendar is No Longer Shown, No Wireless Signal Icon Shown and Resource Monitor Does Not Start

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, calendar, resource-monitor

**1.** Recently I have noticed that I cannot get calendar to pop up after clicking on clock on system tray. I can with searching find settings to configure clock but I can't access calendar at all.

**2.** I no longer see wireless icon with signals showing in system tray.

I tried to customize notification icons and in "Turn System Icons On or Off" I see that "Network" is disabled from changing:

[image]

**3.** I happen to need to access Resource Monitor but it does not work. Tried starting as admin but it didn't help.

**UPDATE:** It appears this also does not work in Safe-Mode, not to mention my secondary Windows 7 account (OS 64-bit, Enterprise)

Would repairing Windows be the way to go or restoring to last good configuration? I also scanned (**sfc /scannow**) files for integrity and all was good.

Comment: If Task Manager doesn't start either, it is likely that the computer has malware on it. Have you tried any anti-malware programs?

Comment: Task Manger works good. Scanned with NOD32 and nothing out of ordinary.

Comment: (1) Do you mean the Calendar widget? If yes, widgets do not show up in the notification area. If not, what product is it? (2) Scan also using the free version of [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/).

Comment: The one that pops up when you click on clock in system tray.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\PreferExternalManifest` and make sure it is not there or set to 0.

If set to 1 as suggested in some how-to's for adapting DPI scaling for older apps, this entry causes the following side effects in Windows 7:

1. Resource monitor (`resmon.exe`) does not start anymore;
2. Network icon not displayed  in taskbar, option is greyed out in system icons;
3. Maintenance center icon not displayed in taskbar and greyed out in system icons;
4. Clock/calendar popup does not display upon left click on taskbar clock.

Comment: I have set it on 1 in hexademical. Below is decimal. Should I change to decimal when changing to o? I heard something about DWORD. Should I restart operating system after that?

Comment: I have been missing on these features for 2 years. I had to use smartphone to scan and connect to wireless networks. I could not use Performance Monitor and whoa! Calendar too? And then comes @azurro to save the day! Thanks my friend. I will now enter time machine and seek you in the past to save myself from the frustration for the future.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution may be found in the article
[Fix for When Clock, Volume, Power or Network Icons are Missing and Grayed Out in Windows Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fix-for-when-clock-volume-power-or-network-icons-are-missing-and-grayed-out-in-windows-vista/)

Open up regedit.exe through the start menu search or run box, and then browse down to the following key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`.
If you see any of the following key names in the right-hand pane, delete them:

- NoTrayItemsDisplay
- HideClock
- HideSCAPower
- HideSCAVolume
- NoAutoTrayNotify
- HideSCANetwork

Do the same to to the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`.

---

From the artice
[System icons do not appear in the notification area in Windows Vista or in Windows 7 until you restart the computer](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/945011?wa=wsignin1.0) :

regedit to
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify` and delete the entries `IconStreams` and `PastIconsStream`, then 
restart the `explorer.exe` process (or logout and login).

Then right-click the taskbar, click on Properties, in the Taskbar tab click
on the Customize button to the right of "Notification area".
Now click `Turn system icons on or off` and set Volume, Network, and Power System to On.
Or alternatively click `Restore default icon behaviors`.

The above Microsoft article also has a Fixit that does the above automatically,
as does this batch file (run as administrator) :

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" /v IconStreams /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" /v PastIconsStream /f
start "Shell Restarter" /d "%systemroot%" /i /normal explorer.exe
```

Comment: Remark: Take backups and create a system restore point before updating the registry.

Comment: Indeed. See [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

Comment: I have Volume and Clock but I don't have Network icon. Clock when clicked no longer pops up calendar and Resource Monitor which worked fine no longer works. Seems Repair or reinstall as last resort is the only way...

Comment: If your Windows installation is very sick, and you have the installation media for it of the exact same service-pack level, see [How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html), which will still keep existing applications.